# Sourcetree - undo removed file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I used "remove" instead of "discard" on a file in Sourcetree.  This deleted the file from my local folder.  I therefore got another copy of the deleted file from the repository on GitLab.  Sourcetree still shows the file as being removed with the minus icon.  How can I undo / remove this from sourcetree?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the changed file in the pending files view and select: "Discard".
This is the git equivalent of:

```
git reset HEAD footer.php
git checkout SERDES_TB2.vhd
```

See http://gitimmersion.com/lab_15.html for more info.